# ng-repeat and json for child pages not showing in li's

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

This has to be a really stupid question; however, I'm learning angular and thought I had everything  working but that's not the case.

I'm not getting any errors through the terminal, or console.  An my first list of li's are displaying.  I'm trying to get the child pages underneath to populate; however, I'm getting nothing.

Here is the html:

```
<nav class="menu-wrap">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="link in links" ng-class="{true: 'dropDown'}[dropDown]">
          <a ng-href="{{link.href}}">
            <i class="{{link.icon}}"></i>
            {{link.name}}
            <span class="{{link.arrowDown}}" ng-click="dropDown != dropDown"></span>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="child in links.child">
              <a ng-href="{{links.child.href}}">
                <i class="{{links.child.icon}}"></i>
                {{links.child.name}}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('PrimaryMenuCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // Set menu to closed
    $scope.open = false;
    $scope.dropDown = false;

    // Toggle open class on click
    $scope.toggle = function() {
      $scope.open = !$scope.open;
      $scope.dropDown = !$scope.dropDown;
    };

    $scope.links = [{
        name: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'fa fa-user',
        href: '#',
        arrowUp: 'fa fa-angle-up',
        arrowDown: 'fa fa-angle-down',
        child: [{
            name: 'Child Page',
            icon: 'fa fa-user',
            href: '#'
        }, {
            name: 'Child Page',
            icon: 'fa fa-user',
            href: '#'
        }, {
            name: 'Child Page',
            icon: 'fa fa-user',
            href: '#'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Post',
        icon: 'fa fa-user',
        href: '#'
    }, {
        name: 'Media',
        icon: 'fa fa-user',
        href: '#'
    }, {
        name: 'Pages',
        icon: 'fa fa-user',
        href: '#'
    }, {
        name: 'Comments',
        icon: 'fa fa-user',
        href: '#',
        arrowUp: 'fa fa-angle-up',
        arrowDown: 'fa fa-angle-down',
        child: [{
            name: 'Child Page',
            icon: 'fa fa-user',
            href: '#'
        }, {
            name: 'Child Page',
            icon: 'fa fa-user',
            href: '#'
        }, {
            name: 'Child Page',
            icon: 'fa fa-user',
            href: '#'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Appearance',
        icon: 'fa fa-user',
        href: '#'
    }, {
        name: 'Plugins',
        icon: 'fa fa-user',
        href: '#'
    }, {
        name: 'Users',
        icon: 'fa fa-user',
        href: '#'
    }];

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using link.child instead of links.child in the ng repeat and use child.X instead of links.child.X in both angular expressions

Answer (score 1):

child is property of link instance

Convert this

```
ng-repeat="child in links.child"
```

to this

```
ng-repeat="child in link.child"
```

Full code of child portion

```
 <li ng-repeat="child in link.child">
              <a ng-href="{{child.href}}">
                <i class="{{child.icon}}"></i>
                {{child.name}}
              </a>
            </li>
```

Comment: Seconded - The reason being is that 'link' is defined in the parent ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="menu-wrap">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="link in links" ng-class="{true: 'dropDown'}[dropDown]">
      <a ng-href="{{link.href}}">
        <i class="{{link.icon}}"></i>
        {{link.name}}
        <span class="{{link.arrowDown}}" ng-click="dropDown != dropDown"></span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="child in links.child">
          <a ng-href="{{child.href}}">
            <i class="{{child.icon}}"></i>
            {{child.name}}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please change your nav html to above one.